# Директива using не нужна - UnityEngine.Advertisements

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity3d, visual-studio-2017

Директива UnityEngine.Advertisements не подтягивается к проекту.

В *Обозреватель решени → Cсылки → ПКМ → Добавить поключенную функцию* (также далее можно выбрать *Найти другие службы*) нет возможности выбрать нужную либу.

Не могу понять как подключить библиотеку. Пожалуйста, помогите.

```
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;    //Директива using не нужна

[RequireComponent(typeof(Button))]
public class UnityAdsButton : MonoBehaviour {

void Start()
{
    Advertisement.    //CS0103 C# Имя "Advertisement" не существует в текущем контексте
}
```

**Использую :**

Unity3D version 2017.2.0f3;

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 
Версия 15.5.1;

Microsoft .NET Framework
Версия 4.6.01055

Comment: ответ сильно зависит от версии юнити, которую вы используете. Дополните в вопросе

Comment: @vmchar, использую Unity3D версию 2017.2.0f3. Уже есть новая версия 2017.3.0f3, если не будет вариентов попробую обновить версию Юнити.

Comment: Эта либа используется только для рекламы, она интегрирована но выключена. Её можно включить. Походу эта статья должна помочь - 
https://unityads.unity3d.com/help/monetization/integration-guide-unity#using-the-asset-package